# 100% Height for Floated, Fluid Child Divs *AND* Parent

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid grid design that incorporates a sticky footer solution. Everything works fine, but the grid container, which basically is an inner wrapper with class "content", will not hold the height of its parent, "siteWrapper". Consequently, the fluid child divs within content won't, either.

I have been researching this issue for longer than I care to admit with no success, so I'm posting here. PLease let me know if you have any ideas.

Here's the HTML structure:

```
    <div class="siteWrapper">

       <header class="mainHeader gridContainer">
            <!--header content-->
        </header>

        <div class="content gridContainer">
            <div class="primaryContent grid-8 group">
                <section>
                    <!--my content-->
                </section>
            </div><!--end primaryContent-->

            <aside class="sideBar grid-4 group">
                <!--my sidebar content-->
            </aside>
       </div><!--end content-->

    </div><!--end siteWrapper-->

    <footer class="mainFooter">
        <div class="footerInner">
            <p>This is the footer</p>
        </div><!--end footerInner-->
    </footer>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* Global
============================== */
html,
body {
        height:100%;
}

.siteWrapper {
        max-width:1140px;
        min-height:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: content-box;
}

.content {
            overflow:auto;
            width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding-bottom: 120px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}

.mainFooter {
        position: relative;
        margin: -120px auto 0 auto; /* negative value of footer height */
        height: 120px;
        clear:both;
}

.primaryContent,
.sideBar {
        vertical-align:top;
}

.content,
.primaryContent,
.sideBar {
    height:100%;
}

.mainHeader,
.mainLogo,
.content,
.primaryContent,
.sideBar {
    display:inline-block;
}

/* Grid Styles
============================== */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    /* Columns
    ============================== */

    .gridContainer > [class^="grid-"] {
        float: left;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .gridContainer > [class^="grid-"]:first-child {
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left:0;
    }

    .gridContainer > [class^="grid-"]:last-child {
        float: right;
        padding-right:0;
    }
    /* Clearfix
    ============================== */

    .group::after,
    .gridContainer::after {
        content:" ";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
```

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tqwMf/ - I just removed the default margin

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. What margin did you remove? I added background colors to the main structure divs - siteWrapper, content, and the two columns. You can see that siteWrapper is at full height, but content (green) shows only the padding applied for the sticky footer and that both columns are collapsed.